# Non-breaking spaces in CanvasJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvasjs

I'm currently working on a project involving both Bootstrap and CanvasJS making a doughnut chart.

Is it possible to make the course title and/or the legend text non-breaking text? I’ve been trying to include `&nbsp;` but it doesn’t seem to be working. The result is “Legend String” and “Doughnut Title” gets put on my doughnut chart:

```
var reviewsData = [
{ y: courses_reviewed, legendText: Legend String}
];

renderMyChart(trackingContainer, trackingData, “Doughnut Title”);
```

Here’s a JFIDDLE demonstrating the above: http://jsfiddle.net/gratiafide/n6r5gsqq/2/

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\xA0` instead of `&nbsp;`
http://jsfiddle.net/9mbhsmv6/

Comment: Thanks, that's a super suggestion!

Comment: In case someone was wondering. `&nbsp;` is html, and CanvasJS likely uses the `.text()` method somewhere, which converts it from its semantic meaning into its raw text. `\xA0` has no such issue as it is the unicode equivalent of `&nbsp;` and is unaffected by calls to `.text()`